# -moz-transition-duration not working?

Tags: firefox, css, css-transitions

below you have the code I'm using to try and achieve a 3D animation:

Here is the fiddle and the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/82C2N/

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>3D CSS Animation</title>
    <style>
        #movieposters li { 
            display:inline; float:left;
            -webkit-perspective: 500; 
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -webkit-transition-property: perspective; 
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s; 
            transition-duration: 1s; 
            -moz-perspective: 500; 
            -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -moz-transition-property: perspective; 

        width: 200px;
        }

        #movieposters li:hover { 
            -webkit-perspective: 5000; 
            -moz-perspective: 5000; 
            transition-duration: 1s; 
            transition-timing-function: linear; 
        width: 200px;
        }

        #movieposters li img { 
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg);
            -webkit-transition-property: transform; 
            transition-duration: 0.5s; 
            -moz-transition-duration: 1s; 
            -moz-transform: rotateY(30deg);
            -moz-transition-property: transform; 

        width: 200px;
        }
        #movieposters li:hover img { 
        width: 200px;
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); 
            -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%" class="bluegradient">
    <ul id="movieposters">
        <li>
            <img src="http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs36/i/2008/252/6/1/House_MD_DVD_covers_by_kdaver.jpg"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

To see the desired effect open that in Chrome. In Firefox, the `-moz-transition-duration` seems to have no effect. The perspective and rotation value change on hover but withou any animation.

Any idea why? I'm using the latest version of Firefox (10.0.2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a problem with the value `transform`, in Mozilla it is prefixed with `-moz-transform`.

```
#movieposters li img {
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform  
}
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cadence96/82C2N/1/